# How I can update a list of lists in python?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists and I want to make modifications on the lists strings.

```
m_list = [['D-1', 'D-2', 'D-3'],
 ['J-3', 'J-4', 'J-5', 'J-6'],
 ['R-1', 'R-2', 'R-3'],
 ['U-1', 'U-2', 'U-3', 'U-4']]
```

I want to change "-" with "00", this is my try:

```
for m in m_list:
    for turbine in m:
        turbine = turbine.replace("-", "00")
        print(turbine)
    print(m)
```

I miss the part of replacing the lists.

This is the result I want:

```
m_list = [['D001', 'D002', 'D003'],
 ['J003', 'J004', 'J005', 'J006'],
 ['R001', 'R002', 'R003'],
 ['U001', 'U002', 'U003', 'U004']]
```

Comment: `print([[j.replace("-", "00") for j in i] for i in m_list])` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using list comprehension:

```
print([[x.replace('-', '00') for x in i] for i in m_list])
```

Or add a `map`:

```
print([list(map(lambda x: x.replace('-', '00'), i)) for i in m_list])
```

Or add two `map`s:

```
print(list(map(lambda i: list(map(lambda x: x.replace('-', '00'), i)), m_list)))
```

Of course, the nested list comprehension is the best.